# Linking to Teamviewer in react native

Tags: android, react-native, deep-linking

I'm currently trying to add a button in React Native in Android that links to the Teamviewer Host app. Whatever url i'm trying, I'm ending up with the following error:

```
  openTeamviewer() {
Linking.openURL('teamviewerhost://open')

Error: Could not open URL 'teamviewerhost://open': No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=teamviewer10://open flg=0x10000000 }
```

Does someone know the right url for Teamviewer Host?

Comment: Is this the official method in Documents of the TeamViewer?

Comment: @hongdevelop it is the method from React Native to interact with a different app and I hoped it was a standard for apps to interact with it. For example, opening WhatsApp works with above code

Comment: Each app has a different way of opening it. `example is Lyft`https://developer.lyft.com/docs/deeplinking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up using [react-native-send-intent](https://github.com/lucasferreira/react-native-send-intent), really easy method to open a different app from React Native on Android:

```
onPress={() => SendIntentAndroid.openApp('com.teamviewer.host.market')}
```